# Textual filter very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 10 to 1000 lines 
I have a text field to filter the table.
I used this code to filter the display of each line depending on the filter:

```
$("#cs_name").keyup(function () {
        $(".cs_line").each(function () {
            if (!$(this).data('name').toLowerCase().includes($("#cs_name").val().toLowerCase())) {
                $(this).hide("fast");
            }
            else {
                $(this).show("fast");
            }
        });
    });
```

It works fine if I have 10 or 20 lines, but when I have 1000 lines time between each letter is sooo long. up to 5 seconds sometimes.

Maybe there is a way to make it mor efficient.

For information, pagination is not an option, for some client reasons, I cannot have multiple pages.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: DOM lookup and manipulation is slow

Comment: Yep I know but I have no choice for this

Comment: well get rid of the animations, lowercase the values to start, store the `$("#cs_name").val().toLowerCase()` into a variable so you are not looking it up on each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with caching `$(this)`. The creation of a `$(this)` object requires time, so create one and cache it : `let $this = $(this)`, and reuse `$this`.

Same thing for `$(".cs_line")` and `$("#cs_name").val().toLowerCase()`. Each of these operations require jQuery to access the DOM and create full jQuery objects, and you're doing that thousands of times.

Also, throttle your keyup, don't execute the filter every time a key is pressed.

Optimized code :

```
const $lines = $(".cs_line")
const name = $("#cs_name").val().toLowerCase()
let typeTimeout = null

const applyFilter = () => {
    $lines.each(() => {
        let $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('name').toLowerCase().includes(name)) {
            $this.show("fast"); // Or just .show(), much faster
        } else {
            $this.hide("fast"); // Or just .hide(), much faster
        }
    });
}

const throttleFilter = () => {
    clearTimeout(typeTimeout);
    typeTimeout = setTimeout(applyfilter, 400) // Will apply the filter if no key is pressed for 400ms
}

$("#cs_name").keyup(throttleFilter);
```

Comment: Perfect solution it's incredibly faster now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tartempion34 and hopefully you know that it is using ES6 which is not going to run in all browsers. You might need to change the fat arrow syntax to functions.

Comment: You're right, but "not all browsers" is the politically correct term to refer to IE, so who really cares :) [ES6 browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option for you is to use [Jquery Datatable](https://datatables.net/). It offers really fast search on multiple columns and other ready-to-use functionality.

**UPDATE**:
Without using JQuery Datatable you can increase performance storing cs_line elements and not retrieving everytime with query selector.

Comment: Sadely ... I can't use it. It's some legacy code and I con't change what I want :(

Comment: I updated my answer but there is no many things you can do IMHO

Comment: @Nicolo allow me to disagree (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would filter the data based on a data attribute so it runs quickly.

```js
/* Just filling table with data */
var trs = $(Array.from({length: 1000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).map( n => `<tr data-name="${n}"><td>${n}</td></tr>`).join(""))

var tbody = $("#tbod").append(trs)
/* end of filling table */

var lastFilter = "", //holds last typed search
    rows = tbody.find("tr");  // table rows
      
/* Normalize the data to start so you are not doing it on every check */
rows.attr("data-name", function (index, value) {
 return value.toLowerCase()
})

$("#filter").on("keyup", function () {
    var currentFilter = this.value.toLowerCase();  //get what was typed and normalize it
    //If the last filter does not match current than we need to reset table rows
    if (!lastFilter || currentFilter.substring(0,currentFilter.length-1) !== lastFilter) {
        rows.removeClass("hidden");
    }
    //store what the filter was for next iteration
    lastFilter = currentFilter;

    //If there is text, filter it
    if (currentFilter) {    
      //Use CSS selector to find it ^ is start, use * for anywhere
      trs.not('tr[data-name^="' + currentFilter + '"]').addClass("hidden")
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="filter" />
<table>
  <tbody id="tbod">
  </tbody>
</table>
```